# непонятное поведение (изменение ширины) элемента <input /> в бустраповском <Card>

Tags: css, css3, reactjs, bootstrap, flexbox

Использую React с Bootstrap (впрочем не важно, что React).

Потребовалось сделать карточку (элемент `<Card>`) в которой будет поле с диапазоном из двух дат, которые можно задать через 2 элемента`<input />`

Т.е. поле должно выглядеть так:

```
с <input /> по <input />
```

При этом сами элементы`<input \>` должны быть одинакового размера, а все поле шириной с `<Card>`

Решил сделать это через `flex` (наверное это можно сделать и классами bootstrap, но я его только начал изучать), получился код (пока без `<input />`:

```
<div className = "element-datepicker">
    <div className = "i1">с</div><div className = "i2">&nbsp;</div><div className = "i3">по</div><div className = "i4">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

получился такой объект, что замечательно, так и как задумывал (цвета нужны для оценки позиционирования):

[image: разметка поля для ввода диапазона дат]

Вот css код:

```
/* === стиль для получения даты === */
.ipc-element-datepicker {
    margin:                 0;
    padding:                0;

    width:                  100%;
    height:                 100%;

    display:                flex;
    flex-direction:         row;
    justify-content:        space-between;
    align-items:            center;

    box-sizing:             border-box;
}

.element-datepicker .i1, 
.element-datepicker .i2, 
.element-datepicker .i3, 
.element-datepicker .i4 {
    margin:                 0;
    padding:                0;
}

.element-datepicker .i1 {
    padding-right:          0.35rem;
    background:             orange;
}
.element-datepicker .i3 {
    padding:                0 0.35rem;
    background:             limegreen;
} 
.element-datepicker .i2,
.element-datepicker .i4 {
    height:                 100%;

    flex-grow:              1;

    background:             red;
}
```

Однако, когда внутрь полей `i2` и `i4` добавляю элементы `<input />`:

```
<div className = "element-datepicker">
    <div className = "i1">с</div><div className = "i2"><input type = 'test' name = 'date-s' /></div><div className = "i3">по</div><div className = "i4"><input type = 'test' name = 'date-f' /></div>
</div>
```

то ширина карточки резко увеличивается и я не могу понять почему так происходит и как с этим побороться

[image: поле для ввода диапазона дат]

получается объект с большей шириной, чем задумывалось

Вот css код для `<input />`

```
.element-datepicker input {
    display:                inline-block;
    margin:                 0;
    padding:                0;

    width:                  100%;
    height:                 50%;

    border:                 1px solid black;
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно решить эту проблему

Comment: Инпуты находятся в дивах с классами i2 и i4 у которых ширина не задана явно, и  ширина в 100% для инпутов не сработает корректно. Кроме того, при вёрстке html класс не задаётся атрибутом className, нужно указывать class="..."

Comment: @Quazimorda className - это из React, я там в самом начале это написал, но это не суть. Но почему когда я не размещал в `i2`, `i4` элементы `<input>` все размеры были корректными (см. рисунок 1), но стоило мне поставить туда `<input>` и все поползло. И ведь даже если я `<input>` жестко задаю размер скажем в `10px`, то все равно блоки `i2`, `i4` расползаются. Вот это поведение непонятно и непонятно что с ним делать кроме как жестко задать размеры через `px, rem, em`

Comment: Вероятно потому, что у инпутов, как и у прочих элементов форм, имеются некоторые свойства по-умолчанию, такие как size - ширина поля ввода, или maxlength - максимальное количество символов в тексте. Вы их в css не переопределяете, может что-то реакт добавляет инлайново в код. Надо смотреть в инспекторе кода, какие именно свойства вы не задавали, а они есть.